# set the variable as constant

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

the SQL gets the latest entry from the table ''users" . and  $check is the variable where it's stored  ,
i want the code run in a way , if the $check get's a value , it remains constant , even if ''users'' get any other latest entry ..

here is my code

```
    <?php
    include 'db.php';
    
    
    $email = isset($_POST['email']);
    $fname = isset($_POST['fname']);
    $user_id = isset($_POST['user_id']);
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=(SELECT max(user_id) FROM users)";
    
    
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   $check=$row['user_id'] ; }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Why are you doing it so complicated? `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: You don't need a loop, since there's just one row.

Comment: `$check` won't change unless you execute this code again after a new row is added.

Answer (score 1):

A little tidy up here.
The query you wish to use, is to get the last added user, and there is no need for a sub-select, as shown in the query below.
Here we use some fake variables, which will be derived from you validation of the POSTed variables.
You will not need to loop over the results with foreach, as the results are directly in the $res variable.

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database", 'oldboot', 'bigkev123');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// validated variables from POST 
$email = 'kev@example.com';
$fname = 'kevvo';
$user_id = 2;

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->fetch();

echo $res['name']."\n";
$check = $res['user_id'];
?>
```